# Configuring Sublime 3 to Build TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, sublimetext3

I am following the AngularJS [start guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) using Sublime. When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
/Users/Audrey/MyDev/node/07tsdemo/app.ts(2,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
/Users/Audrey/MyDev/node/07tsdemo/app.ts(4,1): error TS1205: Decorators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.
/Users/Audrey/MyDev/node/07tsdemo/app.ts(11,7): error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.
[Finished in 2.2s with exit code 2]
[cmd: ['tsc', '/Users/Audrey/MyDev/node/07tsdemo/app.ts']]
[dir: /Users/Audrey/MyDev/node/07tsdemo]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

The other problem is that it seems sublime can't recognize the path and import properly. It's showing me some error in the editor. How can I config this to make it work? Thank you very much!!!

[image]

1. Sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/vidaaudrey/tstest)
2. tsconfig.json

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "out": "built/out.js", 
           "sourceMap": true, 
           "target": "es5"
       }, 
       "files": [
           "app.ts"
       ]
   }
   ```

Comment: What build system are you using? What plugins do you have installed? Is the compiler running in watch mode? What is the **full text** of your "*some error*" in the editor when you are trying to import? Your question is rather unclear as it stands, please [edit] it and add as many details about your setup and what steps you have followed as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured TS compiler in sublime?

1st error: Provide module flag to compiler. Ex: `tsc -m commonjs`. ([Compiler Options](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options)).

2nd error: Target ECMAScript5 `-t es5`. By default the compiler targets ECMAScript 3, the current prevailing standard.

3rd error: Add --experimentalDecorators flag to compiler.

I've downloaded sample from ng-conf and applied this tsconfig (for Windows):

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc","$file"],
    "path": "C:/Users/Artiom/AppData/Roaming/npm",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true, //add this to your config.
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

**Update**

1st red underline: *Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'*

2nd:red under line: Your config misses `experimentalDecorators`. I've told you to add this in original answer. Take a look into my **tsconfig.json**

Comment: Thanks very much Artiom. The build is finished and I can see the final js file. But somehow sublime is still showing the error underline. Do you know how to make it go away? Also, do you have the sublime building config file that I can use for Angular 2? Thanks again

Comment: @AudreyLi provide please a sample to download. Ant what kind of error it shows now? All three as in original question?

Comment: And please provide you tsconfig.json

Comment: I followed your guide and did a little more digging. I use [this build](https://github.com/vidaaudrey/tstest/blob/master/ts.sublime-build). Now the sublime compile is ok. But sublime still has some red error [underline](https://github.com/vidaaudrey/tstest/blob/master/screenshot.png). I wonder if it is because it can't recognize the import module. The test project is [here](https://github.com/vidaaudrey/tstest).

Comment: @AudreyLi updated the answer. Please look again at my config .

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Your config doesn't work at Mac Sublime 3. Got an error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'compilerOptions'. I did have the --experimentalDecorators option on. The build config I had works, the only problem is just the syntax highlighting showing error. I think it's rather an editor problem.

Comment: @AudreyLi your project doesn't have angula2 files. You can run ts compiler manually from command line and it will show you the error

Comment: the angular2 file is here: https://github.com/vidaaudrey/tstest/tree/master/typings/angular2

Answer (score 0):

These settings worked for me,
all errors are gone.

```
{
     "cmd": ["tsc",
     "--module","system",
     "--experimentalDecorators",
     "--target","ES5",
     "--moduleResolution","node",
     "$file"],
     "file_regex": "^(.+?) \\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)(: .+)$",
     "line_regex": "\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)",
     "selector": "source.ts",
     "osx": {
     "path": "/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin"
     }
}
```

Comment: OK, but what file is this?